# Reading text from file using filereader

Tags: java, sql

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","jashan","noor1032"); 
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select STUDENT_ID,STU_NAME,GENDER from STUDENT");
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("E:\\winter 2019\\COMP 230\\table.txt");
while(rs.next())
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
    fw.write(newline+rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
}
fw.close();
FileReader f1=new FileReader("E:\\\\winter 2019\\\\COMP 230\\\\table.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(f1); 
int j;
String s;
while((j=br.read())!=-1)
{
    char ch=(char)j;
    s=new String (String.valueOf(ch));
    System.out.print(s);
    ta.setText(s);
}
f1.close();
```

This is my code to retrieve data from a table and write it into a file and then again retrieve data from the file and display it in a textarea(ta). The data printing in file is ok but it is only displaying the last character inside the textarea rather than displaying whole data. What could be the reason?

Comment: In your while loop, you are updating value of s to new value and previous gets replaced, that's why you see only last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code... you overwrote the value in the textfield everytime instead of concatenating the string and then writing it to the textfield.

```
String s;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while((j=br.read())!=-1)
{
    char ch=(char)j;
    s=new String (String.valueOf(ch));
    System.out.print(s);
    text.append(s);
}
ta.setText(text.toString());

f1.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Apache commons Utilities `FileUtils` class. It has a method

```
public static String readFileToString(File file,
                                      Charset encoding)
                               throws IOException
```

This really should solve all your problems. Look [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString-java.io.File-java.nio.charset.Charset-) for javadoc of this method.
All you will need to do is

```
ta.setText(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("E:\\\\winter 2019\\\\COMP 230\\\\table.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print does not flush, and the error is already mentioned: `ta.setText(s)` will be repeatedly overwrite `ta` with the current character, finally leaving the last character. Also a single backslash is doubled once in a normal "..." string.

But I wanted to mention the new classes [`Path, Paths, and Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). And try-with-resources that closes the files, the connection, the statement and the result set. Also the reading can be done line wise. Where `readLine` delivers the read line without newline, or null on end-of-file.

I have used the Unicode format UTF-8 to store the file, in order to be able to combine any script/special accents.

```
Path path = Paths.get("E:\\winter 2019\\COMP 230\\table.txt");

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
            "...", "..."); 
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
            "select STUDENT_ID,STU_NAME,GENDER from STUDENT");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(path))) {
    pw.print('\uFEFF'); // Maybe write Unicode BOM for Windows Notepad
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
        pw.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
    }
}

try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) { 
    String s;
    while((s = br.readLine())!= null) {}
        System.out.println(s);
        ta.setText(ta.getText() + s + "\r\n");
    }
}
```